# Type file content, pipe some actions and put result back

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, pipelining

Is there way to do something like thas:

```
cat somefile.txt | sort | uniq > somefile.txt
```

I.e. I want to list entire file, then pipe some actions to its content and finally put result back to source file overwriting it completely. For now I doing it by putting output to temporary file and after all moving it over original. I want to do it such simple way like linux piping allows.

Shell is `bash` in Linux and `cmd` in Windows if it is important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(answering for bash)
No. The shell processes redirections first, which then truncates the file. Only then does `cat` start, and it's operating with an empty file.

There is a tool called `sponge` in the `moreutils` package that lets you do this:

```
cat somefile.txt | sort | uniq | sponge somefile.txt
```

This command can be simplified (remove [UUOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat)):

```
sort -u somefile.txt | sponge somefile.txt
```

Without `sponge` you have to write to a temp file, and if the command succeeds, overwrite the input file

```
tmpfile=$(mktemp)
sort -u somefile.txt > "$tmpfile" && mv "$tmpfile" somefile.txt
```

Comment: `sponge` is the general answer, but since `sort` (unlike most utilities) needs to buffer all the data before outputting any (except for `-m`), for this specific case you can instead `sort -u -o somefile.txt somefile.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc 'sort u|x' somefile.txt
```

1. `sort u` sort unique
2. `x` save and close